# In C# student database windows application , insert data if Student_ID not exist and not insert data when Student_ID exist

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created a student database management application and I want to add a feature like if `Student_ID` already exists in the database, then it will show a message that it exists. If `Student_ID` does not yet exist, then it will continue.

Please help me!

My C# windows form application SAVE button_clicked code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Saikat Dutta\Documents\Chemistry.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Student
                                      (Student_ID, Student_Name, Address, DOB, Date_of_admission, Age, Mobile, Parent_Name, Parent_Mobile, Standerd, Subject, Fees, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
                                      VALUES        ('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "' , '" + textBox3.Text + "' , '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' , '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'  ,  '" +  textBox4.Text + "' , '" + textBox5.Text + "' , '" + textBox6.Text + "' , '" + textBox7.Text + "' , '" + textBox8.Text + "' , '" + comboBox1.Text + "' , '" + comboBox2.Text + "', '" + comboBox3.Text + "' , '" + comboBox4.Text + "' , '" + comboBox5.Text + "' , '" + comboBox6.Text + "' , '" + comboBox7.Text + "' , '" + comboBox8.Text + "' , '" + comboBox9.Text + "' , '" + comboBox10.Text + "' , '" + comboBox11.Text + "' , '" + comboBox12.Text + "' , '" + comboBox13.Text + "', '" + comboBox14.Text + "')" , con );

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(" DATABASE SAVED SUCCESSFULLY :-) ");
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the Student table for Students with a matching id.  If the new student id is "13", then the query could look something like:

```
select * from Student where Student_ID = "13"
```

Then, check if the result of the query is empty.  If it is empty, then add the new student, else report it already exists.  Although ideally, the User of the Database System wouldn't pick the student id manually, it would be auto-generated, unless you use something like their social for the id.  In any case, you check results of your query against any fields in the database that are required to be unique.

Comment: its not working still now , please help me with proper code.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to add a feature ...

Then I would put the logic in a stored procedure so you don't repeat that code everywhere you want to use it. This also means you should not use literal, dynamic SQL. Instead pass values using `SqlParameter`s.  And as bonus points the sql will help with "insert or update?"

In the stored procedure  it might look something like this:

```
if not exists ( select userId from users where userId = @userIdParameter )
begin 
    insert into users ....
end
else 
begin

    update users ....
end
```

P.S. Using string concatenation in your sql is strongly discouraged as it very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Putting the text box entries in `SqlParameter`s protects against this.